# Marging or cobmine two rows or more in the dataframe with some condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I hope you are fine
i wonder if you can help me with the following

[image]

I have this type of data and i want to combine all of these three rows in a row with a condition that  conforming other column (it is MD). and it is from the same month.

how can do that using python ?

Comment: so what is your condition ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.